# How to increase CPU core speed of a guest to maximum of Citrix Xenserver Host

Tags: virtualization, hp, hp-proliant, xenserver, citrix

There is a Citrix XenServer 5.5 (HP ML370 G5, Xeon 2GHz) on this Server there is a Windows Guest (Windows 2008 R2 x64) under Properties I set 4 CPU Cores with max prio. But if I check with CPU-Z the performance of the CPU from Host there is set the right CPU (XEON 2GHz) but with only 600MHz what is wrong with this Guest.

The /proc/cpuinfo from Citrix XenServer:

> ```
> processor : 0
> vendor_id : GenuineIntel
> cpu family    : 6
> model     : 15
> model name    : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz
> stepping  : 7
> cpu MHz       : 2000.016
> cache size    : 4096 KB
> fdiv_bug  : no
> hlt_bug       : no
> f00f_bug  : no
> coma_bug  : no
> fpu       : yes
> fpu_exception : yes
> cpuid level   : 10
> wp        : yes
> flags     : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 apic mtrr cmov pat clflush acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht constant_tsc up pni vmx
> bogomips  : 4002.63
> ```

Here is the Outout of CPU-Z from Windows Guest:

[image]

On another Citrix XenServer under Citrix XenServer 6.1 with the same machine it works fine. Is this a failure from Citrix Xenserver or of HP Hardware?

**Update**
The Core speed don't increase if the CPU has load:
[image]

**Update 2**
This is the Output of xenpm

```
# xenpm get-cpufreq-states
Xen cpuidle is not enabled!
Xen cpufreq is not enabled!
```

Comment: Have you installed the XenServer Tools on this Windows Guest?

Comment: Also, [this could be related](http://blogs.citrix.com/2011/07/11/optimise-your-server-for-maximum-performance/) - HP servers can be set to balance energy consumption against performance. They're supposed to scale according to demand, but this doesn't always happen properly. What have you got set in the BIOS for this HP machine?

Comment: No there are no XenServerTools installed because it is a Console Installation of Windows Server. What BIOS Information are interesting for this issue? After load BIOS defaults I only activate the Virtualization Properties.

Comment: If you load the processor, does the clock speed increase? A 6x multiplier is very low.

Comment: I update my post with core speed on max CPU load

Comment: Anybody has a idea what can be the problem? I don't know what can I do now.

Comment: Turn off frequency scaling and power saving modes in the BIOS!

Comment: I could guess that cpu-z just gives wrong results in virtual enviroment. This is the same CPU and frequency can not change.

Comment: I don't think it is a failure of CPU-Z because of another Server in a citrix Environment Show the Right frequency. The BIOS Default is Set to maxpower.

Comment: Can you really imagine that the same physical CPU can serve host staff and VM staff with different frequency at the same time o_O ?

Comment: Could you include the output of `xenpm get-cpufreq-states`? This needs to be run on dom0 (the console)

Comment: The Output from xenpm is posted as update of my question. @veniamin what do you mean with different frequency?

Comment: @kockiren I mean exactly the frequency the real hardware CPU is working on. The same cores execute host code and VM code in time-division mode. They switched from one to another very frequent to speak about some possibility of CPU to tune their frequency then it "dives" to VM code, I think. Unless It is cool visualization feature I am just not aware about.

Comment: @kockiren I could imagine e.g. that hardware-assignment virtualization is switched off and you experience significant performance penalty. To get real picture It is better to run real CPU benchmarking test. For example download evaluatuation copy of PassMark test http://www.passmark.com/products/pt.htm -- and compare It to the result published on this site.